# DataGrip: is it possible to visualize complex SQL queries?

Tags: datagrip

I need some tool for visualization of complex SQL queries. In the simpliest form it should look like http://demo.queryvis.com/. I.e. I paste some very complex SQL query into editor, press button, the diagram is drawn.

Is DataGrip capable of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-1908

But I agree that the feature could be interesting